# Fatal error: Call to undefined method JToolbarHelper::deleteListX() in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

```
protected function addToolBar() 
{
    JToolBarHelper::title(JText::_('COM_HELLOWORLD_MANAGER_HELLOWORLDS'), 'helloworld');
    JToolBarHelper::deleteListX('', 'helloworlds.delete');
    JToolBarHelper::editListX('helloworld.edit');
    JToolBarHelper::addNewX('helloworld.add');
}
```

what is the error in this syntax

Comment: The error says "`undefined ... deleteListX()`" - have you implemented that method? You should atleast add the definition of `JToolBarHelper`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Joomla docs](https://docs.joomla.org/JToolBarHelper), the class JToolBarHelper is defined in

- [administrator/includes/toolbar.php](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/administrator/includes/toolbar.php)

However, there is no such method in that class. Checking the commit history shows that the method was removed in

- [480a506c80 - Remove deprecated CMS code from JToolBarHelper](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/commit/480a506c8024f646dca16d9d7bdd233fbf4f01d4)

So if you are getting this error, your code is written for an older version of Joomla.

The code for `deleteListX` was this:

```
/**
 * Writes a common 'delete' button for a list of records.   
 * Extended version of deleteList() calling hideMainMenu() before Joomla.submitbutton().    
 *  
 * @param   string $msg Postscript for the 'are you sure' message.  
 * @param   string $task An override for the task.  
 * @param   string $alt An override for the alt text.   
 * @since   1.0     
 * @deprecated  
 */     
 static function deleteListX($msg = '', $task = 'remove', $alt = 'JTOOLBAR_DELETE')     
 {  
    self::deleteList($msg, $task, $alt);    
 }
```

As you can see it is only wrapping the call to `deleteList` which is defined as

```
/**
* Writes a common 'delete' button for a list of records.
*
* @param    string $msg Postscript for the 'are you sure' message.
* @param    string $task An override for the task.
* @param    string $alt An override for the alt text.
* @since    1.0
*/
public static function deleteList($msg = '', $task = 'remove', $alt = 'JTOOLBAR_DELETE')
```

So you can replace your

```
JToolBarHelper::deleteListX('', 'helloworlds.delete');
```

with the direct call

```
JToolBarHelper::deleteList('', 'helloworlds.delete')
```

Note that `editListX` and `addNewX` have been removed as well. So you will get the same error for those. Check the removed source code and adjust your methods as needed.

Comment: I use DeleteList but it is not working ..... It doesnot perform any task ......... wt should i do ????????

Comment: @vishal What you should do is figure out why it is not performing any task. Set a breakpoint in your debugger and step through the code.

Comment: @vishal , there could be an java script issue, in my case it checkbox was not being selected , causing an javascript error, you need to add id="adminForm" in the form tag to make it work. Let me know if it worked for you